# Constant V/F ratio control of Induction Machine

Tags: power-electronics

[image]I am trying to simulate the V/F control of open end winding Three Phase Induction Machine, this involves a PI controller to be placed for acting on error(ref speed - actual speed ) of motor. I got stuck at deciding values of gains of PI. What could be the approach to get these values. I can think of going with three phase model of IM but i feel like going in wrong direction. Please let me know your views.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Are you sensing current and slip?

Comment: I am sensing speed of IM and comparing it with reference speed for error generation, then i am using a PI controller and output of this PI is added with the sensed speed to get synchronous speed, later i am deriving frequency out of this speed for generating modulating signals for INVERTER.

Comment: I think you need a lot more specs before you have to decide on Kp, Ki.  but do add 50 mV FS current sensing on DC  and all drivers for debug designed like 50 Ohm test points for power loss sensing.  I highly recommend you search google scholar. All your answers exist.  Depending on load, you want to control acceleration max using Idc

Comment: okay, Thank you sir.